# Filtrar registros com intervalos de tempo pré-definidos no MySQL, usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

estou fazendo um sistema de datalogger e gostaria de saber se existe alguma função intrínseca do MySQL para pegar, na tela de pesquisa de registros, o valor em um intervalo de tempo pré-definido, ou se eu devo programar para comparar se o timestamp é igual ou imediatamente superior ao anterior, criar um array e incluir nele os valores com esse tempo pré-definidos. Caso essa situação só se resolva com programação (No meu caso, estou usando PHP), a ideia de fazer um fetch de todos os registros no intervalo completo de interesse e testando a condição do tempo é a forma mais eficaz/elegante de se fazer?

Por exemplo, os registros são armazenados no banco de dados a cada 30 segundos, mas eu queria fazer um gráfico que pegue apenas os dados de hora em hora. Assim, eu pegaria o primeiro registro, em seguida, eu descartaria do gráfico os registros seguintes cujos valores fossem menores do que 1 hora em relação ao primeiro registro filtrado. Em seguida, iria inserir no gráfico o registro cujo valor fosse 1 hora maior do que o segundo registro filtrado, e assim, sucessivamente. Seria como usar o limit/offset, mas ao invés de filtrar pelo número do registro, seria pela data/hora.

Agradeço desde já o apoio

Comment: Defina precisamente "intervalo de tempo pré-definido". Será sempre um mesmo intervalo com um início e duração fixas? Pode variar algum deles? Algum deles será informado ou devem ser recuperados de seu banco de dados? Você quer apenas os intervalos que contenham algum dado ou quer todos os intervalos mesmo que sem dados?

Comment: Na tela, eu tenho um campo do tipo "text" para indicar a quantidade e um campo do tipo "select" para o usuário informar selecionar: Registros (Todos os registros no período selecionado), Horas (Os registros serão exibidos de hora em hora. Como o banco de dados pega os dados a cada 30 segundos, eu não exibirei no gráfico os registros a cada 30 segundos, e sim, de hora em hora), Dias (Será exibido um único registro por dia, aquele que for o primeiro daquele dia, durante todo o período selecionado), Semana (Será exibido um único registro por semana) e Mês (Será exibido um registro por mês).

Comment: Assim, se eu escolher a opção "Minutos" no campo do tipo "select" e "15" no campo do tipo "text", eu vou querer exibir os registros a cada 15 minutos desde a data/hora inicial até a data/hora final que o usuário definir na busca.

Comment: Você quer apenas o primeiro registro dentro do intervalo de tempo que definir?

Comment: Não. São todos os registros que estejam nesse período de acordo com o intervalo definido. Por exemplo, se o usuário quiser o período entre 01/10/2019 às 15:00 e 10/10/2019 às 19:01, com intervalo de 15 minutos, devem ser exibidos os registros cujo registro dataHora seja 15:00, 15:15, 15:30, 15:45, etc. e não serão exibidos todos os registros a cada 30 segundos.

Comment: Estou usando o seguinte SQL:

SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dataHora BETWEEN "2019/10/01 15:00" AND "2019/10/10 19:01" GROUP BY DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(dataHora, '%Y-%m-%d %H %i'), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) ORDER BY id desc

Mas só são exibidos registros da cada 1 hora e, para  exemplo, deveriam ser a cada 15 minutos